# How to obtain information about downloads, total installation, and active installation from my published android applications programmatically?

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-play

I have a few questions regarding android market(Google play). How can I list my published application by accessing from my google account? What I have done so far is using my application package name as a query string to search my application and display all information which I used [android market api](http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/) to do it. Is there another better way to display all my published or installed applications by accessing from my google accounts?

My second question is about detecting number of downloading and installations of my published application. I have found only google analytics so far(for free) which I need to embedded some codes to monitoring my application. Is it possible for me to access those information from [android market publish page](https://market.android.com/publish/) . I have found that publish page contains information that I need.

Edited: For second question, I would like to obtain statistical information without adding any new code to my application. Is it possible to provide only google account to grant the permission to get those information?

My application is published. If I am using google analytics to monitoring my application do I need to start my counting from zero?

Sorry for my English and my little knowledge about this.

Thanks in advance..

Edited: .. I have found an application, called "analytics" that is what exactly I want to do. But I still cannot figure it out how it works..

Comment: Sorry for unclear questions... For the first question, I have to list my application package before get the list of my application. Actually, from google account it already know what am I publishing right? So, I am thinking there might be another way to do this without knowing the package name. For second question, I wonder that can I obtain information like number of downloads and installs without embedded any code to my application (just only provide google account to grant the permission).

Comment: Ah ok, I don't know that one. I'll let someone else answer it.

Comment: Thanks for quick respond anyway.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only place you will find this kind of information is on your Developer page. That said, if I were wanting to do what you are, I would put up an app on App Engine that either parsed my Dev page on request, or on a schedule. I mention App Engine as personal preference here, you could obviously use anywhere you can host scripts on.

You can then do what you like with the data you have collected, and your app can request this from your site. Assuming you have no qualms with publicising these numbers, you wouldn't need to scare users by authenticating, and would just need a plain html request.

Edit:
In your language of choice, you would need to request your developer page (the one that lists apps and their install count) and would also need to authenticate as yourself to get it. It's for this reason I would use your own hosting if you can. I can't be more specific than this, as I don't know what language you're most likely to be using. It should be trivial to find out how to do an html request and step through the page in whatever language it is though. App Engine pages are written in Java or Python and deployed to the server, while other obvious options are PHP or Perl. On my own server I would most likely use Perl as it's ideal for ripping up html with regexps.

Comment: Can you explain me more about how to parsing my Developer page? Which app do I need to put on App Engine or just put a request script?

Comment: If you were doing it on request, you would just deploy an applet that grabs your page, rips it up, and then spits out the data the Android App is needing.

Comment: You mean grabs the https://market.android.com/publish/ page and split that information one by one? If that so it will take a lot of times and efforts then..  The information there is in flash graph. Is it possible to collect those data also?

Comment: I think you're moving onto a new question re. parsing HTML. Yes there would be lots to parse, but you write code to loop through that, so volume doesn't matter.